# What is the difference between these two forms of Dynamic memory allocation in c++

Tags: c++

When creating a heap object what is the difference between creating it like:

```
TreeNode* n = new Node();
```

and

```
TreeNode* n = new Node;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do the parentheses after the type name make a difference with new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new)

Comment: Ok means, in first case memory will be created with zero initialization and in second case it initializes randomly?

Comment: Does `Node` have a constructor? If it does there is no difference.

Comment: yes, it has default and parameterized constructor.

Comment: The constructor will be called in either form.

Comment: Only default will be called.. Then why do we have two syntax for the same thing?

Comment: Actually there are more.. `TreeNode* n = new Node{};`

Comment: This video should provide some info about history: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs)